# I've recently updated from 15.04 to 15.10 (kubuntu) and now I get some error drm: intel_pipe_config every time I start ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, 15.10

Error:

```
drm: intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
```

Although everything seemed to work fine but when I am playing any video and try to increase or decrease the volume using volume control buttons of the keyboard I get forcefully logged out . And after log in, screen blinks when I resize application windows.